# am unable to add active class to the list

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(window).load(function () {
  // body...
  $(".nav li").click(function () {
    alert('captain');
    $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
section{
  padding-top: 80px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
a:focus{
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-nav li {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.navbar-nav li:hover, .navbar-nav li.active  {
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  color: orange;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover{
  background: transparent !important;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <div class="lnr lnr-menu"></div>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">sample</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Button1">Button 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Button2">Button 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Button3">Button 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Button4">Button 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Button5">Button 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Button6">Button 6</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content">
    <section id="button1"></section>
    <section id="button2"></section>
    <section id="button3"></section>
    <section id="button4"></section>
    <section id="button5"></section>
    <section id="button"></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

When am adding and id to section, the "active" is not working, but when am removing the id's to section it is working fine. can anyone please let me know what mistake I did ?`I changed the class in js but dint find and dint understood the bug, how to fix the bug ?

Comment: Its working. Right? What do you want more than that?

Comment: your code snippet works, please explain what the bug is?  If you want the sections to act like your <li>'s, then you need to add code to do the same thing for sections that you're doing for <li> tags.. they aren't the same.

Comment: yeah it is working here, but in my developed code is is not working, please check the following link, 
http://xylines.com/demo/

thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out your problem. On your link here - http://xylines.com/demo/ - you have a click event for both your anchor (< a >) and its parent (< li >). When you click it, only the anchor click event is firing. So you get your scrolling, but not the active class change.

You can handle both of these inside your anchor click like below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Scroll animation
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        //These two lines handle your active class change
        $('.nav li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent('li').addClass('active');

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $($.attr(this, 'href')).offset().top
        }, 800);
    });
});
```

You can then completely remove this, as it's now handled in the above:

```
$(window).load(function () {
  // body...
  $(".nav li").click(function () {
    alert('captain');
    $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/64acju0t/2/)

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain Updated my answer, I believe I figured out your problem.

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain Check this one here - https://jsfiddle.net/cdtbpfqh/3/. If you combine your two click events (one for 'a' and one for '.nav li') then it seems to work. If you have them separate like you do now, it will only trigger one of them. That's why your scroll works (the 'a' click event fires), but your class swap does not ('li' click does not fire).

Comment: @RiotZeastCaptain Great! Glad we got to the bottom of it! Some of these things are tricky, especially when you can't duplicate it in a fiddle to play around with.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // body...
  $(".nav li").click(function() {
    alert('captain');
    $(".nav li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  })
})
```

```css
section {
  padding-top: 180px;
  min-height: 150vh;
}
a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.navbar-nav li {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}
.navbar-nav li:hover,
.navbar-nav li.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid orange;
  color: orange;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
  background: transparent !important;
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <div class="lnr lnr-menu"></div>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="#">sample</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Button1">Button 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Button2">Button 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Button3">Button 3</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Button4">Button 4</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Button5">Button 5</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#Button6">Button 6</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="content">
    <section id="Button1"></section>
    <section id="Button2"></section>
    <section id="Button3"></section>
    <section id="Button4"></section>
    <section id="Button5"></section>
    <section id="Button"></section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/64acju0t/1/

id wrong written in section make it correct. i hope it will helpful